# Correct form of input arguments in c++

Tags: c++, input, arguments

I am not familiar to c++, so the question may seem silly, but I should run a code (written by other guys) to solve my problem as a comparison.

The input arguments for the code includes the "number of instances" and three other inputs (My issue is with the first input: number of instances).

I have 120 instances so what I do is to write "120 1 1 0" in the field of "input arguments" in the CodeBlocks IDE. But, the code does not solve all those instances for me. Instead, it solves the 120th one. In the same way, if I set for example "4 1 1 0" it only solves the 4th instance. How should I pass the inputs to solve all of them?

p.s. I tried 1-120, 1:120, "1 120", but neither works.

Comment: The meaning of the input arguments is defined by the program, without the program we can't tell you how to call it. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Alan The program is nearly 2000 lines. How can I provide it?

Comment: @Mostafa By removing the parts that are irrelevent, most of the 2000 lines will be about solving whatever it is your program does, only a few will be about passing the input to your solving code. Just post that part, but still post a compilable program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I pass the inputs to solve all of them?

You write a helper function that uses a loop and calls the function from the library inside the loop.

```
void myFunc(int N, int a, int b, int c)
{
   for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i )
   {
      functionFromLibrary(i, a, b, c);
   }
}
```

From your `main` function, call `myFunc` instead of the function from the library.